# unable to execute winrm quickconfig

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, dsc

I am unable to get around the following Powershell remoting error in my Windows 10 Machine.

Firstly I am attempting to execute the following.

```
PS: >Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Verbose -Force -Path $outPath    
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConf
igurationManager,'namespaceName' = root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting 
requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the 
destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm 
quickconfig".
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338012
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

so I do what it suggests by executing this.

```
PS: >winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
winrm : WSManFault
At line:1 char:1
+ winrm quickconfig
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WSManFault:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = More data is available. 
Error number:  -2147024662 0x800700EA
More data is available.
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you running the commands from an elevated prompt? Is UAC enabled? Check [this article](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH200047.html) as well as [this question on SF](http://serverfault.com/q/530903/134295).

Comment: yes it is elevated. I found a DCOM activation issue on my machine relating to the Immersive Shell Application.  I had to change ownership permissions in the registry for the CLSID and APPID from Trusted Installer to Administrators.  I was then able to update the Launch and Activation permission on the Immersive Shell and after reboot all seemed well.